# Text is black on startup --- how to debug?

Tags: themes, colors, aquamacs

I just helped a colleague to configure `package.el`, `smex`, and `ido` and set up a nice theme (`spolsky` from the `sublime-themes` package) for Aquamacs.

When I evaluate `(load-theme 'spolsky t)` everything looks just fine, but when Aquamacs is started, the main text that is supposed to be white is black.  This is fixed when I manually evaluate `(load-theme 'spolsky t)` with `C-x C-e`.

The configuration file is minimal and nowhere do I change any colours explicitly.  The only theme-related line is `(load-theme 'spolsky t)`.

Since this is Aquamacs and not GNU Emacs (which I'm using) I don't really know how to debug this.  (I don't even know how to run a GUI Aquamacs from the command line because I'm completely Mac-illiterate.)

How can I debug this?  There is no error message displayed and the equivalent of `custom.el` does not mention any colours.

Comment: I've never used Aquamacs, but you should be able to run it from the command line using something like `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs`.

Answer (score 1):

The themes installed are stored in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/your-installed-theme/`. You could edit the theme file and investigate what line is causing the text to be black, then restart emacs and see if you caught the evil guy.

But a possibility that comes to my mind is that emacs is using more than one theme, and that generally causes visual glitches. To prevent that, run `M-x customize-themes` and uncheck `Select more than one theme at time`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the cause.  "Select more than one theme at a time" is unchecked.

Comment: I should also note that the theme works fine for me using GNU Emacs 24.5.1 on Fedora.